# error problem with 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Tags: mysql, sql, max, left-join, sql-null

i have 2 tables one (visits) and other one (patients) with relationship by mysql (patients) is with PK as patients.pid and visits.pid as index 
and i wanted to use code in my vb.net app to get the last datetime record to check the patient if still inside the hospital admitted or discharge
so far i have this code with help of you guys

```html
SELECT a.pid,MAX(ISNULL(b.sdat,'1901-01-01')),MAX(ISNULL(b.edat,'1901-01-01')) from patients a left join visits b on a.pid=b.pid Where ddatediff(now(),b.edat) <=365 group by a.pid
```

but when i execute in sql builder using php myadmin  or another app i get error 
(1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL') 
i tried to find out the error cause but no luck until now

Comment: The **documentation** for [ISNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) says..? You probably want to use COALESCE or IFNULL instead. See the respective documentation - someone wrote it, so honor their efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL's `ISNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) is a comparison function, that takes a single argument and returns `1` if it is `NULL`. I think that you meant [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) - or the more standard [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

I would also suggest moving the check outside of the aggregate function, for better efficiency:

```
COALESCE(MAX(b.sdat),'1901-01-01'),
COALESCE(MAX(b.edat),'1901-01-01')
```